# Google play store console splitted .obb

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i got a slight problem on my developed app. When im uploading my splitted obb and app into my google console and wait a few hours, i can donwload it from the app store and it downloads the Expansion file aswell.

But for some reason the Expansion file got renamed from main.7.com.mygame.obb
To temp.main.7.com.mygame.obb

Why google adds temp. To my Expansion files, so my app cant read it?

I have asked google about this problem but never received a mail back. Maybe you got a solution